# shell scripting - groupby

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Hi I have data in a csv file in the following form:

```
url, x, y, z, user id.
abc.com, 1,2,3, qwa12as
wer.com,4,5,6, kdslnca
google.com,43,2,6, anskld12
abc.com, 1,2,3, qwa12as
```

I want to grab the url column and group by the unique user id as a part of my shell script. I know this can be easily achieved in sql, but is there an elegant way to do the same in shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user ID does not appear in other columns (e.g., in the URL) you can select the rows with the user ID with `grep`

```
grep USERID file.csv
```

and then output the first column with `cut` or `sed`

```
grep USERID file.csv | cut -d , -f 1
```

Example

```
$ grep anskld12 test.csv | cut -d , -f 1
google.com
```

Comment: done, thanks again, since I do not have enough reputation points my upvotes didnt show up :)

Comment: can you suggest something for this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824066/filtering-out-values-from-a-column-iteratively-in-shell-script